# Core Data Relationship - Add to existing value

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to set a relationship between inputted core data values. I currently have it set up so when I add the value it creates the relationship in the corresponding entity which I can view in a detail view.

What I am trying to achieve is to add the relationship to a existing value within the entity that is held in a string `RoutineText`. So instead of creating a second identical entry the relationship is added to the new entry. So in the detail view both entries will be viewable.

**The current situation when inputing the values**
[image: The current situation when inputing the values]

So instead of it creating:

**TestName1** ----> **TestName1Detail**

**TestName1** ----> **TestName2Detail**

it would create:

**TestName1** ----> **TestName1Detail** + **TestName2Detail**

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new device
    ExcerciseInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Routines  *routineEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines"inManagedObjectContext:context];

    RoutinesDetails *routineEntityDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoutinesDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Create Relationship
    [routineEntity addRoutinedetObject:routineEntityDetail];

    //Add attribute values
    //[routineEntity setValue: RoutineText  forKey:@"routinename"];
    [routineEntityDetail setValue: info.name  forKey:@"image"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

I hope that is clear.
[image]

Comment: In what way does a to-many relationship not do exactly what you need?

Comment: I have it set as  1 to many but when I add the new attribute value it creates a second value in the original entity as in the `TestName1` description shown above

Comment: so i presume my code is wrong as it isn't achieving what i expect

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Added a picture. I want it to be linked instead of creating a new `Routine` with the same name.

Comment: When I add the new values it duplicates the `Routine` value instead of creating a relationship

Comment: basically it is creating a new object instead of creating a relationship

Comment: im not sure if its an issue in my fetchresultcontroller or the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's acting this way - you're creating a new `Routines` object:

```
Routines  *routineEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines"inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

If you want to associate a new `RoutinesDetails` object with an existing `Routines` object, you don't create a new `Routines` object, you use the one you already have.

Given that the preceding comment explicitly states a new object is being created, and that it refers to a completely different object, I'm guessing you've copied and pasted this code instead of writing it.  I suggest going through the tutorials instead of trying to make somebody else's code work without understanding what is going on.

Comment: Hi Jim. Thank you for pointing that out. I did infact write this from my own knowledge (though limited) with the help of several tutorials. I understand the principle. Would you be able to point me in the right direction as to what to replace it with as I have been at this for several days. :/ Thank you again Jim.

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your application.  If you are displaying a list of `Routines`, then you must be loading the actual `Routines` object that you want to add to at some point.  You just need to pass that through to the place in your application that creates the `RoutinesDetails` object so that it can add to it.

Comment: yeah that was it. I managed to get it working. I was passing the string and not the object. My mistake. Thanks for the help!