# Adding a relationship in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have been at this single task for several days trying to get the relationships between core data entities working. I have achieved this but now I need to change it so that the new attribute value has its relationship added to an existing object. It is a 1 - to - many database.

I am not sure how to add a relationship to a object that already exists. So in the new object that is getting added to RoutineDetail, how would I create the relationship to the object that already exists in the routine Entity?

I have looked at several examples all showing how to add relationships to newly added objects but I need it so the new object in `RoutinesDetails` has a relationship with the value that already exists in `Routines`.

The value of `Routines` is held in a string called `RoutineText`

```
rout is the NSmangedObject for the entity Routines

routDet is the NSmanagedObject for the entity RoutinesDetails
```

I have left the commented out code that allows me to add a relationship when both new objects are created.

This is the last thing I have to do in my project but it is driving me insane. I will be eternally grateful for the fix here. Any advice will be appreciated as this is the best knowledge portal there is. Thank You.

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new device
    ExcerciseInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//rout = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    routdet = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoutinesDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Add attribute values
    //[rout setValue: RoutineText  forKey:@"routinename"];
    [routdet setValue: info.name  forKey:@"image"];

    //Create Relationship
    [rout addRoutinedetObject:routdet];
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686651/core-data-relationship-add-to-existing-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem statement is, I think, here:

> I need it so the new object in RoutinesDetails has a relationship with the value that already exists in Routines.

I presume your data model looks like this:

```
Routine <----> RoutineDetail
```

i.e. every one routine has one routine detail (one-to-one relationship).

But this does not really make any sense. You could simply include the attributes of RoutineDetail in the Routine entity.

Instead of

```
desiredValue = routineDetail.routine.value;
```

you would simply have

```
desiredValue = routineDetail.value;
```

---

*Also, please note that your code has a number of problems. The first line is completely unnecessary, just use* `self.managedObjectContext`. *Additionally, against the convention you are using Capital initials for variables. Those should be reserved for class names. Your method to add the relationship also does not look right.*

You can add a relationship like this, without a method call:

```
routineObject.detail = detailObject;
```

Comment: no my data model is 1 to many.....so you suggest just adding an additional attribute to RoutineDetail?

Comment: What is not working is that I am not sure how to add a relationship to a object that already exists. So in the new object that is getting added to RoutineDetail, how would I create the relationship to the object that already exists in the routine Entity?

Comment: If you add a new object to a to-many relationship, you use the core data generated methods in the form `addRoutineObject:` on the instance of your entity. To add a to-one relationship to an existing object just use the dot notation indicated at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: But that is my issue. I am trying to add the routineDetails relationship to routine. using the core data generated methods but I am having no luck. I can create it when I add both objects in at once but not when I am adding only one object.....

Comment: I have added the picture of the entites